# Reset focus on Vue SPA page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, focus, accessibility, single-page-application

I'm developping Vue SPA with Vue router app and I'm trying to simulate oage reload, by resetting focus state after changing the route. Here is my code:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  document.activeElement.blur();
  next();
});
```

My problem is that focus indeed returns to body element right after change, but on next focus it goes back to where it was, in this case footer, instead of "skip to content" button. I tried setting focus to window explicitly, but it doesn't work either. Does anyone have an idea how to reset focus flow for real, so it truly starts over? Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basing on [this article](https://marcus.io/blog/accessible-routing-vuejs) I added `tabindex -1` right before and removed it right after. It did the trick

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  document.body.setAttribute("tabindex", "-1");
  document.body.focus();
  document.body.removeAttribute("tabindex");
  next();
});
```

Comment: This solution worked for us too. We have places where we load different components without triggering the router. In that case this code can  be put in the `created` function of the component to get the same effect.

Comment: Note that you don't have to remove the `tabindex`.  Leaving it set to -1 is fine.  The user won't be able to TAB to that element (that's what -1 means) but you can still call `focus()` on the element.

Comment: I love this answer but encountered two problems: 1. I ran into trouble when using VoiceOver (see my answer below). 2. It looks like that author wrote an updated article where he concludes focusing on the body is not recommended (https://marcus.io/blog/improved-accessible-routing-vuejs)

Answer (score 0):

The Vue website now has some official documentation for re-focusing on a "Skip Link" after each navigation:

https://vuejs.org/guide/best-practices/accessibility.html#skip-link

Notes:

1. Since this focuses on the Skip Link each time a navigation happens, this means if it's an auto-hiding link, like the one in the Vue docs, it will "pop open" each time you navigate to a different page.
2. I also tried approaches that focus on the body of the page (like [the answer from p-sara](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64061697/1207248)) however I encountered a problem with this and the VoiceOver feature of MacOS. Steps to reproduce this problem: 1. Navigate to a link with the VoiceOver controls (e.g. `ctrl+option+left/right`) 2. Open the link with the VoiceOver controls (`ctrl+option+space`) 3. On the new page, if you continue to navigate with the VoiceOver controls, it won't start from the top, it will continue from where you left off on the page.
3. In my testing, it appears for VoiceOver controls to change focus, the `.focus()` method needs to applied to an element that can receive focus by default (like a link).